# Why is the std::derived_from concept implemented with an additional convertibility test that adds cv-qualifiers?

Tags: c++, c++20, libstdc++, c++-concepts

In the GCC C++20 concepts lib, it has

```
template<typename _Derived, typename _Base>
    concept derived_from = __is_base_of(_Base, _Derived)
    && is_convertible_v<const volatile _Derived*, const volatile _Base*>;
```

1. Why is requiring just `__is_base_of(_Base, _Derived)` not enough?
2. What is the need to use `const volatile` in the test?

Answer (score 15):

The behavior of `std::derived_from` is specified in terms of [unambiguous public inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from)

> The concept `derived_from<Derived, Base>` is satisfied if and only if
> `Base` is a class type that is either `Derived` or a public and
> unambiguous base of `Derived`, ignoring cv-qualifiers.
>
> Note that this behaviour is different to `std::is_base_of` when `Base`
> is a private or protected base of `Derived`.

`__is_base_of` is the compiler intrinsic that is used to implement `std::is_base_of`. So using it alone would not produce the desired behavior.

So to check the "unambiguous public" part of the requirement, we may check if a pointer to a derived object is implicitly convertible into a pointer to a base object. That's just standard procedure with C++ classes. The pointers are convertible if the classes model an "is-a" relationship, public inheritance and not from multiple bases.

The `const volatile` addition is to handle the requirement of "ignoring cv-qualifiers". By always adding them, the conversion is legal even if for example `_Derived` is `B const` to some `A` (non-const) `_Base`. Comparing the pointers as-is would try to convert `B const*` to `A*`, and would fail on account of discarded cv-qualifiers.

Answer (score 8):

1. __is_base_of is not sufficient, because a private base is still a base, and the trait checks for (in words of [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/derived_from)):

> The concept `derived_from<Derived, Base>` is satisfied if and only if Base is a class type that is either Derived or a **public and unambiguous** base of Derived, **ignoring cv-qualifiers**.
>
> Note that this behaviour is different to std::is_base_of when Base is a private or protected base of Derived.

2. `const volatile` is needed because the traits is supposed to ignore cv-qualifiers. A pointer to `T` implicitly converts to pointer to `const volatile T`, while to opposite is not true.